# /dev/sda5 clean

Tags: 14.04

I was updating Ubuntu 16.04 from Ubuntu 14.04, but while installing packages it started to show tty screen then I rebooted my machine.

On startup it start to show a message like *starting show plymouth......* .I googled and found a command `dpkg --configure -a`.
After running this command my machine displaying message

```
/dev/sda5 :clean, 649920/318464 files, 11434504/12720128 blocks
```

and not getting started.

Comment: I suppose that by "not getting started" you mean you do not get the desktop? Is there any disk activity (led) ?  If you press Ctrl Alt F1, do you get a login window + prompt ?

Answer (score 0):

**Step #1:**

Lets first check your file system for errors.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors

**Step #2:**

- type `sudo blkid`
- type `cat /etc/fstab`
- put the output from the previous two steps into your question, and I'll take a look
- type `reboot`